# ARCore supported devices Huawei related

Tags: android, arcore, huawei-mobile-services

I need your advice I am going to buy huawei model y9 that is launched in 2019.But it has 3 models y9/y9s/y9 prime each OS is above 8.0.But in official documentation of ARCORE supported devices it is mentioned only y9(2019).Does it means y9s/y9 prime does not support arcore?Can you guide me please.

Answer (score 0):

only the y9 model is supported, if y9s for exemple is also supported it will be in the list but it's not.

Comment: Thank you,you help me in making my decision easy.